# Outlook Add in - is there some way I can be notified when a calendar item starts?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm thinking of writing an Outlook add in, and one thing I want to do is show a messagebox every time something in my calendar starts. I have looked at all the properties and events for the AppointmentItem class and haven't found anything of value.

Do someone know if there is a way for me to somehow perhaps add an event which is activated whenever a calendar item begins? Or in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook calendar has a default reminder. You can access this at -

```
Outlook > Tools > Options > calendar
```

Here, you have a default reminder setting which will pop up a reminder window every time there is a calendar event. You can set this to 0 mins, so the pop up will be displayed every time some event in your calendar starts.

So, if this is what you want then you might not have to develop your own Outlook addin :)

Comment: Thankyou Pavanred, but unfortunately I want to do other things as well!